# What is the exact definition of a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition

In some book I found, a metric on a non-empty set $X$ defined as a map
$$X\times X\to \Bbb R^{+}$$
and some other place as
$$X\times X\to \Bbb R$$
So, is a metric a real valued function or a non-negative real valued function or it doesn't matter at all?

Since metric is a generalization of distance on the real line. I was convinced by the first definition. But the second one? I don't know and the worst part is, it is widely used definition.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^+\subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Surely the "other places" write $X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ but later write $d(x, y)\ge 0$ as an axiom.

Comment: I hope your definition of $\Bbb R^+$ is what I call $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ and not $\Bbb R_{>0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $X \times X \to \Bbb R^+$, you don't need to note that $d(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$, since it is already implied by the use of $\Bbb R^+$. If you write only $X \times X \to \Bbb R$, you must call the attention to this fact.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't read far enough when you looked at "some other place." If you had, you'd see nonnegativity is included as an axiom. Metrics always take nonnegative values.

Comment: *Metrics always take nonnegative values.* Blumenthal's Boolean metrics don't even necessarily take real number values.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I'm assuming you're being coy. A Boolean metric isn't a metric, just as a semi-Riemannian metric isn't a metric. The intent of the OP's question is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

A metric on $X$ is a map $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R$ that satisfies certain conditions:

- $\forall x,y\in X\  d(x,y)\ge 0$
- $\forall x,y\in X\  \text{if }d(x,y)=0\text{ then }x=y$
- $\forall x,y,z\in X\ d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

The first condition implies $d:X\times X\to [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Also $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Comment: @JonWarneke : Correct!! Haste makes waste --- I felt a qualm, a thought that maybe I forgot something. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Non-negativity of a metric is implied by the axioms that define it. This can be seen in the following way. Take any $x, y \in X$. Then from the triangle inequality, we have $d(x, y) + d(y, x) \ge d(x, x)$. But from symmetry of the metric, $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$, so that $2d(x, y) \ge d(x, x)$. And from the fact that $d(x, x) = 0$, we get $d(x, y) \ge 0$.

Sometimes $d(x, y) \ge 0$ is taken as an axiom depending on whose definition you use, but all these definitions are equivalent.